# Installing the unix-2.7.0.1 package using Cabal, haskell origin

Tags: windows, haskell, cabal, cabal-install

It all started with hdevtools.

I installed the SublimeHaskell package for Sublime 3 on my Windows 7 machine and got an warning saying that hdevtools couldn't be found, or something along those lines. So I thought I might try to install that package using Cabal.

I have Cygwin installed and in my Path working fine. I try a `cabal install hdevtools` I get some scary things:

```
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring unix-2.7.0.1...
Warning: Unknown extensions: CApiFFI, InterruptibleFFI
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-compiler, --with-gcc
cygwin warning:
  MS-DOS style path detected: C:\Users\Stas\AppData\Roaming\cabal/share/config.site
  Preferred POSIX equivalent is: /cygdrive/c/Users/Stas/AppData/Roaming/cabal/share/config.site
  CYGWIN environment variable option "nodosfilewarning" turns off this warning.
  Consult the user's guide for more details about POSIX paths:
    http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
```

... (many checks that seem okay)

```
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-cygwin
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-cygwin
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-cygwin
checking for library containing sem_close... no
configure: Not found
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating unix.buildinfo
config.status: creating include/HsUnixConfig.h
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-compiler, --with-gcc
cabal: Package unix-2.7.0.1 can't be built on this system.
Failed to install unix-2.7.0.1
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
hdevtools-0.1.0.5 depends on unix-2.7.0.1 which failed to install.
unix-2.7.0.1 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

So I think, maybe I should install the unix-2.7.0.1 package. Here goes a `cabal install unix-2.7.0.1`. I actually end up with what seems to be the exact same output, with cabal telling me that unix-2.7.0.1 simply cannot be built on my system. I get the same result when I try to build it manually through downloading the .tar file and configure/building it with `runhaskell Setup build` in the unpacked directory after a seemingly successful `runhaskell Setup configure`.

Can anyone illuminate me as to why I cannot build unix-2.7.0.1 on my Windows 7 machine?

Comment: What’s the output of `ghc --version`? (Assuming you’re using GHC.)

Comment: The output is `The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.6.3`

Comment: No luck. I updated, got a different result after trying to cabal install hdevtools. I ended up having ghc-path and unix not being able to be installed, so I tried each of those separately. Installing unix through caball still didn't yield anything different and cabal installing ghc-paths yields `cannot satisfy -package Cabal-1.16.0`

Comment: You won’t be able to use cabal-install to upgrade unix. Remove all your packages, uninstall GHC 7.6, and install GHC 7.8; it should come with unix-2.7.x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per http://hackage.haskell.org/package/unix, the unix package, which provides bindings to unix system libraries, is not supported under windows.